# how delegate-handle work in ionic + angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, angularjs-directive

Could you please tell me how delegate-handle work in ionic? I made a demo in code pen. I want to scroll the content to the top on button click. But my code is not working when I scroll my content and then press button but my scroll does not go to the top why?
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wavoXb

```
var app=angular.module('app',['ionic']);
app.controller('MainCtrl',function($scope){
   $scope.scrollMainToTop = function() {
    $ionicScrollDelegate.$getByHandle('mainScroll').scrollTop();
  };
  $scope.scrollSmallToTop = function() {
    $ionicScrollDelegate.$getByHandle('small').scrollTop();
  };
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to inject $ionicScrollDelegate in the controller.

```
   app.controller('MainCtrl',function($scope,$ionicScrollDelegate){
   $scope.scrollMainToTop = function() {
    $ionicScrollDelegate.$getByHandle('mainScroll').scrollTop();
  };
  $scope.scrollSmallToTop = function() {
    $ionicScrollDelegate.$getByHandle('small').scrollTop();
  };
```

Comment: I don't why but this codepen is not loading angular. Here is a plukr http://plnkr.co/edit/IchoK4SwXsm0KaUdZEX1?p=preview

Comment: please check I use scrollBottom function but that was nor working..Thanks for ansering

Comment: Updated the plunkr. check ii. http://plnkr.co/edit/IchoK4SwXsm0KaUdZEX1?p=preview